# ValueError when reading a sas file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

**pandas.read_sas()** prints traceback messages that I cannot remove. The problem is it prints messages for EACH row it's reading, so when I try to read the whole file it just freezes printing too much.

I tried from other stackoverflow answers

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')
```

And

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

And

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''<script>
code_show_err=false; 
function code_toggle_err() {
 if (code_show_err){
 $('div.output_stderr').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.output_stderr').show();
 }
 code_show_err = !code_show_err
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle_err);
</script>
To toggle on/off output_stderr, click <a 
href="javascript:code_toggle_err()">here</a>.''')
```

But nothing works.

The message it prints is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last) pandas\io\sas\sas.pyx in pandas.io.sas._sas.rle_decompress()
>
> ValueError: Unexpected non-zero end_of_first_byte
>
> Exception ignored in:
>   'pandas.io.sas._sas.Parser.process_byte_array_with_data' Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "pandas\io\sas\sas.pyx", line 29, in
>   pandas.io.sas._sas.rle_decompress ValueError: Unexpected non-zero
>   end_of_first_byte

Comment: That's not a warning, that's why what you're doing does not work.

Comment: What you are getting is an Exception, not a warning, take a look at `try/except` to catch exceptions

Comment: @FlyingTeller that will work, but that will stop the reading of the file by pandas. My guess is that the file is corrupted, or pandas has a bug. Maybe something related to different versions of the file.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel pd.read_sas() returns something, it read the file, it just throws a message (exception or warning I don't know) but it works. The problem is it prints the message at each row (if I put chunksize=10, there will be 10 messages) so impossible to read the file which is of millions of rows

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel I tried with format='sas7bdat' without improvement

Comment: @Félix then it looks like some sort of bug in pandas. You should go to their issues and see if anyone has reported that and if now opening a new issue report.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel alright, thanks for your help. I found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sas7bdat which works great with my issue. Thanks all!

Comment: @Félix great. Looking around, there are issues with compressed SAS files.

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in the traceback, the error is caused by a bug in the `pandas` implementation of  RLE decompression, which is used when the SAS dataset is exported using CHAR (RLE) compression.

Note the `pandas` issue created for this topic: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31243

The resolution that `pandas` implemented for this bug in `read_sas` is contained in the following Pull Request, which is part of the version 1.5 milestone, yet to be released at the time of answering: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/47113

To answer your question, you have two options:

1. Wait until `pandas` releases version 1.5, update to that version, and `read_sas` should then work as expected. You've already been waiting awhile since you asked, so I suspect this will be fine.
2. Use the python `sas7bdat` library instead (https://pypi.org/project/sas7bdat/), and then convert to a `pandas` DataFrame:

```
    from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
    df = SAS7BDAT("./path/to/file.sas7bdat").to_data_frame()
```

The `sas7bdat` approach worked for me, after facing the exact same error as you did.